# When I run `sudo passwd` I set my password and the script exits okay. Running `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash` immediately after fails

Tags: ubuntu, bash, passwd, sh

Long time lurker, first time poster.

My linux server is behaving strangely. When I run `sudo passwd`, I can set my password up correctly. However, if I run `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash`, the command returns the error:

```
chsh: PAM: Authentication failure
```

When I run `sudo echo "hi"`, I get as output:

```
hi
```

I can provide more details if requested. I have repeated this step three times and I am 100% sure that I am typing my password correctly.

`$ cat /etc/*release`

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Thank you!

[screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i39NV.png)

Answer (score 1):

I am a dumb
`$ sudo passwd alexander`

```
You can now choose the new password or passphrase.

A valid password should be a mix of upper and lower case letters,
digits, and other characters.  You can use a 12 character long
password with characters from at least 3 of these 4 classes, or
an 8 character long password containing characters from all the
classes.  An upper case letter that begins the password and a
digit that ends it do not count towards the number of character
classes used.

A passphrase should be of at least 3 words, 16 to 40 characters
long, and contain enough different characters.

Alternatively, if no one else can see your terminal now, you can
pick this as your password: "claw5Met8sword".

Enter new password:
Re-type new password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Followed by
`$ chsh -s /bin/bash`